# Laravel: Encode JSON responses in UTF-8

Tags: json, laravel, utf-8, laravel-middleware

I want to encode the JSON responses of my API to UTF-8, but every time I make a response I don't want to do this:

```
return response()->json($res,200,['Content-type'=>'application/json;charset=utf-8'],JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

So I thought about making a middleware for all API routes which `handle(...)` function would be this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->header('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
    return $next($request);
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work, the `Content-type` header of my responses is still `application/json` and not `application/json; charset=utf-8`; maybe because the `json(...)` function already sets a `Content-type` header and I cannot override it.

How should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to do it other way around, you want to use **after** [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#defining-middleware).

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: `$request->header('key', 'default')` is a getter in that line you are doing NOP (no operation).

Comment: You're right. I added `$response = $next($request);` and replaced `$request` by `$response` but the header didn't change.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Its right there in the documentation, you want to use **after** middleware (following code is from top of my head and it should work):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AfterMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        /** @var array $data */ // you need to return array from controller
        $data = $next($request);

        return response()->json($data, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Charset' => 'utf-8'],
        JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
}
```

With above approach we can spot two anti-patterns:

- First, crafting response in middleware (you should do it in **controller**).
- Also, maybe using un-escaped `JSON` response should be avoided, because Laravel creators made default the "escaping to plain-text" for a reason, but if all your Web-API's Client-Apps support `UTF-8`, then un-escaped improves performance.

  > Experience shows that most clients beside supporting it, they even assume `UTF-8` if `charset` is missing from `Content-Type` header.

#### Removing middleware and using controller only

Put following code in **app/Http/Controller.php**

```
protected function jsonResponse($data, $code = 200)
{
    return response()->json($data, $code,
        ['Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Charset' => 'utf-8'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

in any of the controllers that are extended by base controller (app/Http/Controller.php) you can use `$this->jsonResponse($data);`

### How pros do it

They use [eloquent resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources) or if there is more going on [fractal](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/) is the way to go (in Laravel use spatie wrapper - https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal).

Comment: Ok but how do I pass the HTTP status?

Comment: Exactly! See you wanted to use the wrong tool. I am updating my answer hold tight.

Comment: Detailed and straight to the mark. keep going @Kyslik

Comment: Hello, How i can pass my 'status code' in Middleware?

Comment: But how would you use the utf8 with the Resource?

Answer (score 0):

In your `JsonResource` class just add:

```php
/**
 * Customize the outgoing response for the resource.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Response
 * @return void
 */
public function withResponse($request, $response)
{
    $charset = $request->header('Accept-Charset', 'utf-8');
    if ($charset === 'utf-8') {
        $response->header('Charset', 'utf-8');
        $response->header('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
        $response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
    // Alternative: iso-8859-1 which will be encoded by default using json escaping.
}
```

I want to note that when using single resources and collections together you must implement this for both: `JsonResource` AND `ResourceCollection`. Using something like `EventResource::collection($events->get())` does NOT work.

[Source: Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/38136#discussioncomment-2248981)

Answer (score 0):

For flutter mobile app we are decoding the coming response using jsonDecode(response.data). So here i'm using

```
$response = array();
$response['status] = 200;
$response['data] = $data;
echo json_encode($response);
```

After this inside flutter App development code you can decode the coming response using

```
var json = jsonDecode(response.data)
```