# force encoding to work on request made for laravel api by web browser

Tags: laravel, rest, api, laravel-5, encoding

I am maintaning an `API` that have some `requests` made by a `front-end app`. When I call it from `postman`, all work well, including its `encoding`. The `response` is:

`{ "message": "Esse nome de usuário está disponível" }`

However, when I make it from `browser`, I receive:

`{"message":"Esse nome de usu\u00e1rio est\u00e1 dispon\u00edvel"}`

I already made [this](https://medium.com/@DarkGhostHunter/laravel-convert-to-json-all-responses-automatically-c4a72b2fd3ac) tutorial, that creates an `middleware` forcing the `encoding`, and on my project I set it like this, unlike the code it sugests:

```
$request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$request->headers->set('Charset', 'utf-8');
```

In `postman`, I saw that these `headers` were not setted in the `response` of the `request`.

Also, I already tried to set in my `controller` response:

```
return response()->json([
                'message' => __('auth.nickname_available'), 
            ], 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Charset' => 'utf-8']);
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717005/laravel-encode-json-responses-in-utf-8/50717612) tip. But neither worked.

How can I can make this work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you properly try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50717612/9193055) solution? The following works for me:

```
return response()->json(
    [
        'Message' => 'Esse nome de usuário está disponível',
    ],
    200,
    ['Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Charset' => 'utf-8'],
    JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
);
```

In the response in your question you forgot to add `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`